# Perl module for parsing natural language time duration specifications (similar to the "at" command)?

Tags: perl, parsing, duration, timespec

I'm writing a perl script that takes a "duration" option, and I'd like to be able to specify this duration in a fairly flexible manner, as opposed to only taking a single unit (e.g. number of seconds). The UNIX `at` command implements this kind of behavior, by allowing specifications such as "now + 3 hours + 2 days". For my program, the "now" part is implied, so I just want to parse the stuff after the plus sign. (Note: the `at` command also parses exact date specifications, but I only want to parse durations.)

Is there a perl module for parsing duration specifications like this? I don't need the exact syntax accepted by `at`, just any reasonable syntax for specifying time durations.

---

Edit: Basically, I want something like [DateTime::Format::Flexible](http://search.cpan.org/~thinc/DateTime-Format-Flexible-0.15/) for durations instead of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with [Time::Duration::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Time-Duration-Parse-0.06/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Duration) and [DateTime::Format::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Duration):

```
use DateTime::Duration;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
        pattern => '%e days, %H hours'
);

my $dur = $formatter->parse_duration('2 days, 5 hours');
my $dt = DateTime->now->add_duration($dur);
```

Comment: `DateTime::Format::Duration` does not seem to accept flexible time specifications. You can make up your own time specification, but then it will only parse *exactly* that spec. Case in point, your example wouldn't work unless you did `$formatter->parse_duration('0 years, 0 months, 2 days, 5 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds')`.

Answer (score 0):

[Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::ParseDate) has pretty [flexible syntax for relative times](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::ParseDate#Relative_time_formats:).  Note that it always returns an absolute time, so you can't tell the difference between "now + 3 hours + 2 days" and "3 hours + 2 days" (both of those are valid inputs to `parsedate`, and will return the same value).  You could subtract `time` if you want to get a duration instead.

Also, it doesn't return [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) objects, just a UNIX epoch time.  I don't know if that's a problem for your application.